# Calculate the Probability of 2 Negatively Correlated Outcomes

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, correlation, python

How does one calculate the probabilities of 2 outcomes that are negatively correlated (A happens and B happens, A happens and B doesn't happen, B happens and A doesn't happen, neither A or B happen)?

How does one calculate the probability of 2 outcomes that are negatively correlated?

I believe using the formula below, you can calculate the probability of 2 outcomes that are positively correlated (is this formula correct?), but I am not sure how to translate this to work with a negative correlation value:
[image]

I assume these all use the formula below and you simply plugin in the different P(A) and P(B) values. Please correct me if that is wrong.

How does one calculate the probabilities of 2 outcomes that are negatively correlated (A happens and B happens, A happens and B doesn't happen, B happens and A doesn't happen, neither A or B happen)?

How does one calculate the probability of 2 outcomes that are negatively correlated?

I believe using the formula below, you can calculate the probability of 2 outcomes that are positively correlated (is this formula correct?), but I am not sure how to translate this to work with a negative correlation value: enter image description here

The formula doesn't seem to work with these values though (trying to solve for neither A or B occuring): A = 0.1 | B = 0.1 | Corr: -.72

When ever a = .1 and b=.1 and the correlation value is -.72, the formula above produces -0.0548, which doesn't seem right since the probability can't be negative, can it?

Assuming the correlation is 0, the probability should be, 0.01. With a negative correlation, wouldn't it be lower than 0.01? and with a positive correlation, it would be higher than 0.01?

Here is my python code being used:
`a * b + corr * math.sqrt(a * (1 - a) * b * (1 - b))`

Comment: The formula is correct as long as $\ 0<P(A)< 1\ $ and $\ 0< P(B)<1\ $, regardless of the sign of  $\ \rho_{AB}\ $.  Your question is ambiguous, however. Do you want to know the probability $\ P\left( A^c\cap B^c\right)\ $ that *neither* of the events occurs, or the probability $\ P\left((A\cap B)^c\right)\ $ that not both of them occur.

Comment: Sorry the question is ambigous! Thank you for helping! I want to know the probability (more so how to calculate) that neither occur (10%, 10%), one of each (10%, 90% & 90%, 10%) and that both (90%, 90%) given the correlation value. Would these all use the same formula except take different P(a) and P(b) (10% each for the neither instance, and 90% each for the both instance?)

Comment: When ever a = .1 and b=.1 and the correlation value is -.72, the formula above produces -0.0548, which doesn't seem right since the probability can't be negative, can it? - -Here is my python code `a * b + corr * math.sqrt(a * (1 - a) * b * (1 - b))`

Comment: Since the correlation $\ \rho_{AB}\ $ between $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ is $\ \frac{P(A\cap B)-P(A)P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)P(B) (1-P(A))(1-P(B))}}\ $ by definition, it must be greater than $\ \frac{-P(A)P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)P(B) (1-P(A))(1-P(B))}}\ $. When $\ P(A)=P(B)=0.1\ $ this turns out to be $\ -\frac{1}{9}=-0.111\dots\ $, so it's impossible for $\ \rho_{AB}\ $ to be $\ -0.72\ $ in this case.

Comment: Okay, so say that means, hypothetically, the max negative correlation 2 events with these probabilities can have is -0.111, correct? So then say, you observed events with these probabilities occurring with a correlation negative correlation below -0.111, could you assume -0.111 in your calculation for the probabilities of the different outcomes?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  It's *impossible* for you to observe events with those probabilities and a correlation below $\ -\frac{1}{9}\ $, so it doesn't make any sense to assume otherwise.

I should, however, correct one error in my previous comment.  The correlation $\ \rho_{AB}\ $ can be *equal* to $\ \frac{-P(A)P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)P(B)(1-P(A))(1-P(B))}}\ $.  This will be the case when $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are disjoint events, which can occur as long as  $\ P(A)+P(B)\le1\ $.